# Dismiss tooltip on tapping anywhere on iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, tooltip

I am developing an application in which I am implementing tooltips on iOS apps. In my app, I wish that tooltip gets dismissed when user taps anywhere else on the screen.
On the screen, there can be other buttons, text field, dropdown or just nothing. I want that tooltip gets dismissed when user clicks on any of these (basically anywhere on the screen). Please suggest what should I do

Comment: Are you using custom tooltips?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to just add a transparent button on top of everything whenever you show your tooltip. In your view controller add the following code.

```
@interface yourViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *tooltipButton;

@end

- (void)showTooltip {
    // your code to show the tooltip goes here

    self.tooltipButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.tooltipButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tooltipButton.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.tooltipButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tooltipButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tooltipButton];
}

- (void)tooltipButtonPressed {
    [self.tooltipButton removeFromSuperview];

    // your code to remove the tooltip goes here
}
```